# How to sum three fields data from three tables in same database

Tags: sum, field

I have table called Sound like this

### id        name    hit

- 100          sam      12
- 101          zad      10

and other table caled SoundK like this

### id        name    hit

- 102          qwe      12
- 103          rty      10

and other table caled SoundD like this

### id        name    hit

- 104          asd      12
- 105          xcv      10

so how to calculate the fields (hit) as total  for all three tables Sound+SoundK+SoundD

Thanks in advance

RGDS for All

Answer (score 0):

In a generic way, you can union the three tables together since they share the same data and then do a sum.

```
select sum(hit)
from (
    select hit
    from Sound
    union
    select hit
    from SoundK
    union
    select hit
    from SoundD
)
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks your answer , But when I try to apply there was an Error

Comment: pls correct the code to :<?php
include "config.php";
?>
  <?php
$results =  mysql_query("SELECT sum(hit),as total from (
    select hit
    from sound
    union
    select hit
    from soundK
    union
    select hit
    from soundD ") ;

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) {
?>
<?php
echo $row[total];?>
<?php
 }?>
is it correct ??

Comment: I'd need to see the error.  I'm not a PHP guy, but if the error was SQL related I'd probably be able to help.  You can try Nouman's code above as is. My code was a general idea, his is more syntactically correct. It's basically the same thing, but might be better performing based on your setup as it sums the three tables separately without union-ing all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM (soundsum) FROM (
SELECT SUM(hit) AS SoundSum FROM Sound AS s
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(hit) AS SoundSum FROM SoundK AS s
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(hit) AS SoundSum FROM SoundD AS s
) X
```

Comment: Dear nouman Zakir
pls make the code for me:owing Im new in php

<?php
include "config.php";
?>
  <?php
$results =  mysql_query("SELECT sum(linkhit),as total from (
    select linkhit
    from sound_link
    union
    select linkhit
    from sound_linkK
    union
    select linkhit
    from sound_linkD ") ;

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) {
?>
<?php
echo $row[total];?>
<?php
 }?>

thanks in advance

ameer